# How to take the first two values but not equal to a specific value for each row

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```
      df = read.table(text="chr    pos    X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8    X9   X10   
    Chr11 24398311 Chr21 Chr21 Chr21 Chr21 Chr21 Chr21 Chr21  Chr11 Chr11 Chr17
    Chr21   788729 Chr21 Chr21 Chr21 Chr21 Chr21 Chr11 Chr21  Chr11 Chr11 Chr17
    Chr21  1780922 Chr21 Chr21 Chr21 Chr17 Chr21 Chr11 Chr21  Chr11 Chr11 Chr17
    Chr21  2935462 Chr21 Chr21 Chr21 Chr11 Chr21 Chr17 Chr21  Chr11 Chr11 Chr17
    Chr21  3072338 Chr21 Chr21 Chr21 Chr21 Chr21 Chr11 Chr11  Chr11 Chr11 Chr17
    Chr21  3130954 Chr21 Chr21 Chr17 Chr21 Chr21 Chr17 Chr21  Chr11 Chr11 Chr17
    Chr21  3238190 Chr21 Chr21 Chr21 Chr17 Chr17 Chr11 Chr21  Chr11 Chr11 Chr17", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

I would like to pull out the first two values appeared from left to right for each row but they are not "Chr21" . The expected result:

```
      chr    pos    L1    L2
    Chr11 24398311 Chr11 Chr11
    Chr21   788729 Chr11 Chr11
    Chr21  1780922 Chr17 Chr11
    Chr21  2935462 Chr11 Chr17
    Chr21  3072338 Chr11 Chr11
    Chr21  3130954 Chr17 Chr17
    Chr21  3238190 Chr17 Chr17
```

Thank you for helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `data.table`-package:

```
library(data.table)

melt(setDT(df), id = 1:2)[value != 'Chr21', value[1:2], by = .(chr, pos)
                          ][, dcast(.SD, chr + pos ~ rowid(chr, pos, prefix = 'L'))]
```

which gives:

> ```
>      chr      pos    L1    L2
> 1: Chr11 24398311 Chr11 Chr11
> 2: Chr21   788729 Chr11 Chr11
> 3: Chr21  1780922 Chr17 Chr11
> 4: Chr21  2935462 Chr11 Chr17
> 5: Chr21  3072338 Chr11 Chr11
> 6: Chr21  3130954 Chr17 Chr17
> 7: Chr21  3238190 Chr17 Chr17
> ```

---

The same logic applied with `tidyverse`-packages:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  gather(k, v, X1:X10) %>% 
  filter(v != 'Chr21') %>% 
  group_by(chr, pos) %>% 
  slice(1:2) %>% 
  mutate(k2 = paste0('L',row_number())) %>% 
  select(-k) %>% 
  spread(k2, v)
```

Answer (score 3):

In `base-R` one solution can be achieved using `apply` row-wise and then `cbind` with 1st two columns:

```
cbind(df[,1:2],t(apply(df[,3:ncol(df)], 1, function(x)x[x!="Chr21"][1:2])))

# chr      pos     1     2
# 1 Chr11 24398311 Chr11 Chr11
# 2 Chr21   788729 Chr11 Chr11
# 3 Chr21  1780922 Chr17 Chr11
# 4 Chr21  2935462 Chr11 Chr17
# 5 Chr21  3072338 Chr11 Chr11
# 6 Chr21  3130954 Chr17 Chr17
# 7 Chr21  3238190 Chr17 Chr17
```